# How to execute code before making a call on Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sip, pbx, agi, dialplan

I have an asterisk pbx server. I’m new to asterisk, I know there are dial plans extensions groups etc. 
My goal is to handle a dial event do some checks then decide whether to let the call go through or not. 
I read about ARI AGI AMI and dial plan but I got confused and don’t know how to proceed. 
I just want to execute code (call an API for example) when any number is dialed, and drop the call or let it through according to that.

I know if I do more research I can get something working, but honestly I don’t have time. I just need to know where to look.

Comment: Unfortanly no answer for your question. Need know how you actualy DO call and what control it(usually dialplan).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I solved it. In case anyone needs this, here's what I did.

I used AsterNET fastAGI and created my service script, which does whatever checks I need and calls `HangUp()` when needed, else just returns and lets the call go through. 
Then I called the fastAGI script in the dial plan and it's working perfectly.